# Prove that two base generates the same topology

Tags: general-topology, solution-verification

I am studying general topology, and here's the question.

> Let $B=\{(a,b) \subset R \mid a,b\in Q,\; a< b\}$, $B’=\{(a/2^n,b/2^n) \subset R \mid a,b,n\in Z,\; a< b\}$. Show that $B$ and $B'$ generates the same topology.

And here's my solution :

Since $B' \subset B$ by definition, it is obvious that topology generated by $B'$ is included in topology generated by $B$.

And, for any $a, b \in Q$, they can be expressed by binary system. i.e, $a=\sum_{n} {a_n}/{2^n}$ and $b=\sum_{n} {b_n}/{2^n}$ where $a_i, b_i$ is 0 or 1.

Then, $(a, b)=\cup _{n} (\sum_{i=-\infty} ^{n} {a_i}/{2^i}, \sum_{i=-\infty} ^{n} {b_i}/{2^i})$.(*)

And since $(\sum_{i=-\infty} ^{n} {a_i}/{2^i}, \sum_{i=-\infty} ^{n} {b_i}/{2^i})$ is contained in topology generated by $B'$, $(a, b)$ is contained in topology generated by $B'$.

So, every open set in topology generated by $B$ is included in topology generated by $B'$

My question is:

1. Is the part $(*)$ correct?
2. Is there something wrong in my solution?

Answer (score 1):

This would work if the underlying space were the set of positive reals, but $(*)$ doesn’t take care of intervals with a negative endpoint. An approach that avoids that difficulty altogether is to note that

$$(a,b)=\bigcup_{n\ge n(a,b)}\left(a+\frac1{2^n},b-\frac1{2^n}\right)\,,$$

where

$$n(a,b)=\min\left\{n\in\Bbb N:\frac1{2^n}<\frac12(b-a)\right\}\,.$$

Now for $n\in\Bbb Z^+$ let $A_n=\left\{\frac{k}{2^{n+1}}:k\in\Bbb Z\right\}$. The distance between adjacent points of $A_n$ is $\frac1{2^{n+1}}$, which is less than the length of the intervals $\left(a,a+\frac1{2^n}\right)$ and $\left(b-\frac1{2^n},b\right)$, so

$$A_n\cap\left(a,a+\frac1{2^n}\right)\ne\varnothing\ne A_n\cap\left(b-\frac1{2^n},b\right)\,.$$

Let $a_n'\in A_n\cap\left(a,a+\frac1{2^n}\right)$ and $b_n'\in A_n\cap\left(b-\frac1{2^n},b\right)$; then $(a_n',b_n')\in B'$, and $$a<a_n'<a+\frac1{2^n}<b-\frac1{2^n}<b_n'<b$$ for $n\ge n(a,b)$, and it follows that

$$(a,b)=\bigcup_{n\ge n(a,b)}(a',b')\,.$$

Comment: But, how can we say that $(a+\frac1{2^n} , b-\frac1{2^n})$ is in topology generated by $B'$? Can we just say that since $a, b$ can be expressed by binary system?

Comment: @Moon: You are of course right. I apologize: it appears that I simply forgot to complete the argument, but I’ve now done so.